# Regional Language (Tamil) font is not displaying

Tags: sql, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application that saves user-entered text to a database.

I'm using Google input tool to enter the data in my mother tongue language Tamil (India).

The text looks correct when I enter it in the text box, but when I retrieve the saved data from database its displaying as `??????`.

Comment: Can you display some sample code to show how you retrieve data from your database?

Comment: This is what i entered மோதிரம் (means Ring) I'm getting this ??????? @KevinHogg

Comment: In order to pin-point where the issue is readers would need to see a sample of your work (you can make it up if it shows the issue).  With that said, if entering the data manually appears correctly it is either the data in the database that is wrong, or the code you use to retrieve the data. Without sample code it's very difficult to guess the issue. Note sample code is your c# or vb code, not the data you're trying to display

Comment: As I'm doing the project in 3 tire archi its difficult to show the full code here... The other data which is in English retrieving correctly. problem only with the "Tamil font"... I hope, I didnt misunderstood your expectation in the last comment. Do I? @KevinHogg

Comment: Are you sure the font you are using for display can handle Tamil characters (try and output some fixed text)? Are you sure the value arrived correctly in the database (use the db-tools to check. You did use an `nvarchar` column, I hope?)

Comment: while typing via Google i/p tool,it can display at all font type which all supports English. even though I used a specific font which supports Tamil font named 'Latha'... data arrived in the database correctly I checked with a English font name, I'm getting the problem only when I enter in tamil. I'm using 'varchar(max)' in column @HansKesting

Comment: Oops... I'm sorry guys, I need to use nVarchar... problem solved thanks @HansKesting

Comment: @Jack Post an answer to your own question and accept it, so that others don't attempt to answer this question.

Comment: I will do... thanks for the guidance please vote up for the question if it make sense I'm blocked to ask any more question ... @KevinHogg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Data type of the column in the database should be nVarchar not varchar or something else.

Answer (score 0):

The column should be **nvarchar**

And when using Tsql Insert statement make sure you use **N**'மோதிரம்'

The prefix N denotes that the subsequent string is in Unicode.

```
Insert into Tamil_language values (1, N'மோதிரம்')
Insert into Tamil_language values (2, 'மோதிரம்')

Select * from Tamil_language
Output
i      j
----------- ----------
1      மோதிரம்
2      ???????
```

*Based On [Answer By Balmukund](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4d08b0b3-f397-43a4-99bf-76189e0a51fa/storing-tamil-text-to-database?forum=sqlgetstarted)*

*(its an old post ! still it may help someone i guess..)*